# Historical Price API in AUD

Tags: historical-trade-data, currencies

I'm looking for an API that displays historical data for cryptocurrencies. I have a list of requirements, in rough order of importance:

- Price in AUD (I don't care about other currencies)
- Multiple cryptocurrencies (at least the major ones, but the more the better)
- Returns historical data, not just current price (just the last week/month is fine)
- Updated hourly or more

I've found a bunch of APIs and they all do two, maybe three of my requirements if I'm lucky, but never all.

I'm going to be graphing this data in Python/Django website, so I could either use a native Python API, make an HTTP request to get a JSON or CSV response, or display someone else's graph in an iframe like this API I found that shows a pricebox for BitCoin:

```
    <iframe src="https://cryptocoincharts.info/webmasters/priceBox/btc/aud" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" frameborder="0" />
```

Does anybody know of an API that would suit my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this is the future, I ended up going with the [Poloniex API](https://poloniex.com/support/api/). It has everything apart from prices in AUD. From there I convert USD to AUD for values as I need them.

Answer (score 0):

Binance API combined with the Blockchain.info AUD to BTC conversion might be what you're after.
Worth mentioning that you don't need to register for some silly API key (yet)
e.g

[AUD TO BTC](https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=AUD&value=500)

[BTC TO USDT](https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT)